# Change script code on URL hash change

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, triggers

I have a script, as is shown in the following example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _myplug = _myplug || {};
_myplug.key = '12e9u349u43098j8r940rjciocjo';
_myplug.renderTo = '';
window.myplug||(function(d) {
    var s,c,o=myplug=function(){ o._.push(arguments)};o._=[];
    s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];c=d.createElement('script');
    c.type='text/javascript';c.charset='utf-8';c.async=true;
    c.src='js/loader.js?';s.parentNode.insertBefore(c,s);
})(document);
</script>
```

I know exactly what change I have to do, but I have no idea how to accomplish this in coding language.

What I need to do is:

- When the URL hash changes to "triggerURL" then `_myplug.renderTo = 'happy';`
- When URL hash changes again to anything else than "triggerURL" then
  `_myplug.renderTo = ''`

This because the URL can change anytime (without leaving the page) and every time the above hash changes happen, the other described changes need to be done some way.

Anyone with a solution..... Thanks a LOT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _myplug = _myplug || {};
_myplug.key = '12e9u349u43098j8r940rjciocjo';
_myplug.renderTo = '';
window.myplug||(function(d) {
    var s,c,o=myplug=function(){ o._.push(arguments)};o._=[];
    s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];c=d.createElement('script');
    c.type='text/javascript';c.charset='utf-8';c.async=true;
    c.src='js/loader.js?';s.parentNode.insertBefore(c,s);
})(document);    

function changeHash () {
   var hash = (window.location.hash || '#').slice(1);
   if (hash === 'triggerURL') {
       _myplug.renderTo = 'happy';
   } else {
       _myplug.renderTo = '';
   }
}

changeHash(); // init 
window.addEventListener('hashchange', changeHash, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much respondents, for your quick replies Excuse me for my "very good" script knowledge, but can anybody post the entire script? This because I have not enough knowledge to integrate the solutions into the existing script. Thank you. (@Dmitriy Loskutov, @ZachRabbit). There must be one place to learn it (I learn a lot here).

Comment: Wow it works. But only when I reload the page (it gets triggered on the right URL hash). Do you know how to let this work without page refresh, but whenever the specified hash changes appear, even without a page reload? That is the actual goal. Thank you.

Comment: Does your `_myplug` support this feature(track hashchange)? In some cases you have to init `_myplug.renderTo = ""` before script is loaded. If your `_myplug` does not support it, so, probably, you don't need to track hashchange event at all.

Comment: Yes, I think this is the best way to prove that: When I reopen the page on the URL ending with #triggerURL then myplug appears in the element with the ID 'happy' (that is what _myplug.renderTo is for). When I reopen the page on the URL ending with any other hash, then myplug appears on the other place, not in the element with ID 'happy', so the myplug is doiing the job based on the URL hash, so your addition to my script code (that tracks hashchange) is working correctly. But some other thing needs to be added to tell the script not only on page load whether the hash = happy or not, but also..

Comment: In a nutshell: Currently the hash tracking works only when I reload the page, but I am searching for a way to also track hash changes that appear when the page is not reload. (I will delete my duplicate comment)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `hashchange` event on `window` to perform your changes. In modern browsers, it's as easy as this:

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function (ev) {
    if (window.location.hash === '#triggerURL') {
        // Your Code Here
    }
}, false)
```

You can find more information, as well as a polyfill for older browsers, on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/hashchange).

Comment: Thank you, it works (see further implementation of this as posted by @Dmitriy Loskutov. But it works only when I reload the page (it gets triggered on the right URL hash). Do you know how to let this work without page refresh, but whenever the specified hash changes appear, even without a page reload? Maybe I need to refire the script, as it does on reload? Thank you.